# Extracting data from model to variables

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, firebase

I'm new to typescript and angular and I was trying to fetch some data from firebase using angularfire2 and assign it to variables to use in some other functions later. I'm  only familiar with javascript dot notation where I access members of the object using dot notation seems like it doesn't work with angular can somebody please help me with extracting data from the model to variables, please

I'm still having a hard time understanding Observable and subscribes too.

code

model

```
export class Reacts {
  sad?: number;
  happy?: number;
  neutral?: number;
}
```

service

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import {
  AngularFirestore,
  AngularFirestoreCollection,
  AngularFirestoreDocument
} from "angularfire2/firestore";
import { Reacts } from "../models/reacts";
import { Observable } from "rxjs";
@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root"
})
export class ReactService {
  mapCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<Reacts>;
  reacts: Observable<Reacts[]>;

  constructor(public afs: AngularFirestoreDocument) {
    this.reacts = this.afs.collection("reacts").valueChanges();
  }

  getItems() {
    return this.reacts;
  }
}
```

component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { Reacts } from 'src/app/models/reacts';
import { ReactService } from 'src/app/services/react.service';

@Component({
  selector: "app-reacts",
  templateUrl: "./reacts.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./reacts.component.css"]
})
export class ReactsComponent implements OnInit {


  react: Reacts[];
  happy: number;
  sad: number;
  neutral:number;


  constructor(private reactsService: ReactService ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.reactsService.getItems().subscribe(reacts => {
      this.react = reacts;
      console.log(reacts); //this works print an array object of data from database
      this.happy= reacts.happy// what i'm trying to achieve
    });
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I'll break it down for you. You are trying to access `.happy` but it is actually an array of `React[]`

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.reactsService.getItems().subscribe((reacts:Reacts[]) => { // Note I have defined its model type
      this.react = reacts;
      console.log(reacts); //this works print an array object of data from database
      //this.happy= reacts.happy // Now VS code will show you error itself
      this.happy = reacts[0].happy; 
    });
  }
```

The power of typscript comes as it is strongly typed language. If you'll make changes as below in service, the VS Code will itself explain you the error:

```
export class ReactService {
  mapCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<Reacts>;
  reacts: Observable<Reacts[]>;

  constructor(public afs: AngularFirestoreDocument) {
    this.reacts = this.afs.collection("reacts").valueChanges();
  }

  getItems(): Observable<Reacts[]> { // added return type
    return this.reacts;
  }
}
```

Once I provide return type of `getItems()` , you dont even have to define type in `.subscribe((reacts:Reacts[])` as I have done in your component.

Comment: Thank you so much sir. now only i understood it. It works like a charm now.